# Storage calculation in snowflake

Tags: storage, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake for the table which has 1 GB of data with it, we can check the same by navigating to
**Database** --> **table** --> **mytable** --> **size** column
to verify the amount of data stored.

While I check the data usage under the **Account** tab --> **usage** section it is coming up with data usage in MB (6 mb). Why is there a huge difference?

One more question if I clone: how to check whether the cloned DB has consumed storage space or not?

Answer (score 0):

When you clone a database, it doesn't consume any additional storage until you start changing/adding data to the clone.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but the hard part for me here is to understand is at what ratio the data has been compressed by Snowflake , when i see through table its is showing up 1 GB of data but which is not the case when i see through Account -> usage tab there its showing only 6MB of data . How?